# How to know which task manager my flink job is running on?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm running a flink job on flink yarn cluster, and the parallelism is set to 1, so this job should be running on one of the task managers, how to know which task manager it is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use the Web-Interface of the job-manager you just have to select any task in the overview of a job and find the assigned task-manager at the very right:

[image]

Hope that helps